# Add, remove, and display methods

Tags: java

I'm tasked with a project to create a program of a multi-dimensional array that holds First name, Last name, phone number, and age.  I'm currently getting the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    input cannot be resolved

```
at Lab2.<init>(Lab2.java:19)
at Lab2.main(Lab2.java:7)
```

**Editx2, I think I figured it out.  I'd ideally like to remove contacts by first and last name, but I can't figure it out.  I tried added a new sysout prompting for last name like I did for first name and then adding another if statement, but it ended up doing something funky instead.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab2 {
    static String[][] contacts = new String[10][4];

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        new Lab2();
    }

    public Lab2() {
        String[][] contacts = new String[10][4];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to my Contacts Directory.  Enter a selection below: ");

        while(true) {
            System.out.println("1: Add a contact");
            System.out.println("2: Remove a contact");
            System.out.println("3: Display your contacts");
            System.out.println("0: Exit the Contacts Directory");

            int userChoice = input.nextInt();

            switch(userChoice) {
        case 1:         
            addContacts(contacts);
            break;

        case 2:
            removeContacts(contacts);
            break;

        case 3:
            displayContacts(contacts);
            break;

        case 0:
            System.out.println("You are leaving the directory! Goodbye!");
            System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void addContacts(String[][] contacts) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter First Name");
        String fName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Last Name");
        String lName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Phone Number");
        String num = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Age");
        String age = input.nextLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                if (contacts[i][0] == null || contacts[i][0].equals(null)) {
                    contacts[i][0] = fName;
                    contacts[i][1] = lName;
                    contacts[i][2] = num;
                    contacts[i][3] = age;
                    boolean Inserted = true;
                    break;


            }
        }
    }

    private static void removeContacts(String[][] contacts) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the first name of the contact you want to remove: ");
        String removeContact = input.nextLine();
        if (removeContact != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < contacts[i].length; j++) {
                    if (removeContact.equals(contacts[i][j])) {
                        contacts[i][0] = null;
                        contacts[i][1] = null;
                        contacts[i][2] = null;
                        contacts[i][3] = null;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }


    private static void displayContacts(String[][] contacts) {
        for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < contacts[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println(contacts[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a similar answer on here but I couldn't figure it out from their code.  Its pretty identical.

Comment: The removeContacts method isn't working

Comment: the role of the constructor is to initialize instance variables, you codes has lots of unnecessary stuff in it. I would suggest that you move the while loop out of it.

Comment: Imran Ali-- I couldn't figure out how to move the while loop out of the constructor.  Everything I tried resulted in errors.  I'm always open to suggestions though.

Answer (score -1):

Your "input" variable [object] is not a global variable, it's a scoped variable in another function.